# apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes Not found

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created the kubernetes cluster with the version 1.19.11. Here, the metric-server installed by default. Now, I had hit the below queries,

kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"

it return "Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource".
So, Please help me to resolve the issues?.

Comment: Could you please tell more about the Kubernetes cluster that you are having? Is it a bare metal solution or a cloud-managed one? Is it `AKS` (looking from tags) by any chance? Can you see it in the `$ kubectl api-resources | grep metric`?

Comment: $ kubectl api-resources | grep metric
nodes                                          metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1            false        NodeMetrics  
pods                                           metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1            true         PodMetrics

Comment: try issuing `kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"`. Notice `external` in API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `minikube`, try starting with the addon enabled `--addons="metrics-server"`. For example:

```
minikube start \
    --kubernetes-version=v1.25.2 \
    --addons="dashboard" \
    --addons="metrics-server" \
    --addons="ingress" \
    --addons="ingress-dns" \
    --feature-gates=EphemeralContainers=true
```